# Trouble retrieving information from json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've managed to extract the information about a user using AJAX as an object. Here is the information that is returned:

```
Object
0: "27"
1: "BORDAS"
2: "Marie"
3: "3"
4: "1978-01-13"
5: "comm"
6: "mus"
date_n: "1978-01-13"
loisirs: "mus"
nom: "BORDAS"
num: "27"
prenom: "Marie"
service: "comm"
titre: "3"
```

The code I wrote to retrieve the information is :

```
$.ajax( {
    url: 'edit.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
data: { id: person }
}).done( function( results ) {
console.log( results );
console.log( results.prenom );
});
```

As you can see above the information is being retrieved correctly however when I do the console.log( results.prenom ) the response is always 'undefined'.

How can I get the individual bits of information from the object?

Thanks.

---

I've managed to get it working by looping over the object:

```
$.each( results, function( key, value ) {
    console.log( value.prenom );
});
```

With the loop the output from console.log is the name of the person, which I wanted. Is there any way of achieving the same result without the loop? (as I know there will only ever be one object)

Comment: use success callback- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same, but success is deprecated. The documentation warns that it will be removed in some future version.

Comment: the output you write above your method is the result of first console.log or you imagine this would be the output?

Comment: The output is the real output from console.log( results );

Comment: Diode: thanks for the answer but Philipp is correct. Success will be dropped in favor of done.

Comment: As added in the edit, it does work properly if I loop over results